# How to make Android App from existing Angular web app using Cordova?

Tags: android, angular, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I have an Angular project web app, which is running successfully in the Apache web server after I built it with "ng build ..." command. Now, I want to make it Android App, for that, I tried to use `Cordova`. First I create a Cordova project then under www directory, I placed `dist` files from NG. Yes, I also used the Cordova platform add android before that. But, when I install apk in an emulator or on a real device it is appearing blank.

I google and found many links but none of them worked for me. Maybe I am doing wrong. Please guide me.

Comment: Did you try to connect with a remote debugger (for android it's chrome)? Is an error printed to console? Are the javascript files loaded (network tab)?

Comment: No I didn't try to connect with a remote debugger . Please guide me how I make this app using cordova, do you have any links where I can follow the steps>

Comment: A useful link has been provided below by  Bahri Can Karakoyun. Compare the steps taken there to the steps you did. If you already did it exactly as the post describes, then you need to debug your app and see where it fails. This can be done by using a remote debugger as described here: https://geeklearning.io/apache-cordova-and-remote-debugging-on-android/

Comment: @pascalpuetz & Bahri Can Karakoyun, from ur given reference and also from this link https://medium.com/@nacojohn/convert-your-angular-project-to-mobile-app-using-cordova-f0384a7711a6  I tried it. Now, I am facing blustack and on real android device the following issue: "Application Error - The connection to the server was unsuccessful. (file:///android_asset/www/index.html)"

Answer (score -1):

You need to be change base url at your dist folder and i don't suggest cordova for angular. You can choose the Nativescript for mobile apps and it's native. Because Cordova plugins are not very compatible with Angular.

Comment: So you suggest he rewrites all of his UI when he already has an existing codebase and hybrid is totally fine for his case? This "advice" is not really helpful. Cordova DOES work very well with angular (see Ionic Framework). It's more like picking the right tool for the right job.

Comment: I don't suggest Cordova for this project. Nativescript is good for native libraries. I reply the answer. I use Cordova and Ionic 3 years but Nativescript is better than Cordova.

Comment: I don't say rewrite.

Comment: You have to rewrite the UI if you switch from "vanilla" angular to nativescript.

Comment: Bro i don't say switch your project Cordova to Nativescript. I just say you can use Nativescript and i don't say rewrite this project with nativescript or you must use nativescript. I just giving an advice for another projects. This advice maybe wrong maybe true. It' s open for discussion but i repeat i don't say rewrite this project with Nativescript. By the way i give a solution for this issue.

Comment: @pascalpuetz thanks for your understanding, you understand my situation clearly. Please guide me how I can make this app using cordova, do you have any links where I can follow the steps>

Comment: @BRwebdesignsolution here is https://medium.com/@EliaPalme/how-to-wrap-an-angular-app-with-apache-cordova-909024a25d79

Comment: @BRwebdesignsolution The link provided by  Bahri Can Karakoyun is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: @pascalpuetz &  Bahri Can Karakoyun, from ur given reference and also from this link https://medium.com/@nacojohn/convert-your-angular-project-to-mobile-app-using-cordova-f0384a7711a6 I tried it. Now, I am facing blustack and on real android device the following issue: "Application Error - The connection to the server was unsuccessful. (file:///android_asset/www/index.html)"

Comment: @pascalpuetz can you please help me to solve "Application Error - The connection to the server was unsuccessful. (file:///android_asset/www/index.html)"